# Any way to continue using Google Backup & Sync on an older MB Pro (mid-2009)?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, google-apps

I have an older (mid-2009, 13 inch) Macbook Pro (MacBookPro5,5) running Yosemite (10.10.5).  Lately whenever I start up or shut down, a dialog pops up letting me know that Google Backup & Sync is no longer supported for older operating systems, and that I need to upgrade my OS to Sierra (10.12) or higher in order to continue using it.  Unfortunately Sierra is [not supported on this model laptop](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp742?locale=en_US), so upgrading the OS is not an option.

Am I just out of luck?  Is there any way to continue to use Backup & Sync on this computer, or will I have to find an alternative cloud sync solution (e.g. Dropbox)?

(Fine print: I am aware that [there is a patch](http://dosdude1.com/sierrapatch.html) that supposedly makes it possible to install Sierra on this model MBP. I have tried installing Sierra using that patch, without success, so for now I seem to be stuck with Yosemite.  If anybody knows another way to get this computer upgraded to 10.12 or higher I would appreciate that.)

Comment: Personally, I think you're out of luck as that is quite an old MacBook Pro. I did a quick google search and it appears that it's unsupported but it may still sync using the Google Backup & Sync version installed on Yosemite? The only thing I can suggest is to manually upload/download files from the Google Drive website, but this would be cumbersome if you're frequently accessing files from the cloud.

Comment: A nice alternative you could consider is rclone, if nothing else works out